# Accessing a previously drawn plot in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I draw a plot like this:

```
var items = $.get("./moonlight_sonata_diameter.data", function(data) {

    items = data.split(/\r?\n/).map( pair => pair.split(/\s+/).map(Number) );

    $(function () {

    plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
                  [ { data: linePoints} ], {
                        series: {
                            lines: { show: true }
                        },
                        crosshair: { mode: "x" },
                        grid: { hoverable: true, autoHighlight: false },
                        yaxis: { min: 0, max: 5 }

                    });
      });
  });
```

Now at a later moment in time, I want to update the crosshair of the plot. However, because it is embedded in so many functions, I don't know how to access it as I am not familiar with jQuery.

Within the script, I can run:

```
plot.setCrosshair({x: 100})
```

However, in another script, at another time, there is no object called plot. Is there a way to access it still?

Comment: can you create the jsfiddle for this, It would be easy to solve your problem.

Comment: I see that plot is part of window, but still it's not doing it in index.html: window.plot.setCrosshair({x: 500}) See: http://plnkr.co/edit/QW9gOtIhgocKByCRBm6G?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have put your plot creation code in document ready function and your 
    plot.setCrosshair({x:100}) is executed just before your plot creation code. so A simple settimeout will do the trick.

just replace

```
 plot.setCrosshair({x: 4})
```

with

```
 setTimeout(function(){  plot.setCrosshair({x: 41})}, 3000);
```

and this will work fine. if you call your setCrosshair function after loading the complete dom then you will not need of setTimeout function. I hope this will help and if not then let me know.
Check it at http://plnkr.co/edit/3cMHmzWEIk6c39mblb0Z?p=preview